# PHP execute function after full file transfer

Tags: php, file, buffer

I'm coding a download counter and I'd like to know if it is possible to execute code after the buffer (here, a file sent with readfile) have been fully sent by the server and received by the client. Please note I cannot use any clientside language, as I am transferring the file directly (not using XHR or/and FileSystem javascript API).

Is it doable in any way?

Thanks!

Comment: Is PHP acting as the server or client here?

Comment: May I remember you PHP is a serverside language? Not a clientside one.

Comment: @gravgun Actually, it's not used as client-side, but if you want you can.

Comment: Depends on how you get PHP to the client side. If you use an interpreter, OK, you can run PHP code on the client. However, if the client must send code to the server which then parses and executes it, here comes a **huge** security problem.

Comment: I believe he wanted to know if the file will be downloaded by the server or by the user/browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> possible to execute code after the buffer (here, a file sent with readfile) have been fully sent by the server

Yes....

```
<?php
readfile($_GET['i_am_so_vuln']);
print "whoops!";
```

....was that so hard?

> and received by the client

No - because you don't when that is. It could be buffered at multiple points on the intervening network. (or even cached).

Comment: You're right... Apart from interacting directly with the HTTP server (Apache, which is not doable on my hosting service), it seems impossible to run code after a full file transfer (I'm also thinking of those "download accelerators" which uses multiple connections). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If it is a file being downloaded by the user, I think you can't `echo` anything. I just tested. The file is prompted, it finishes and nothing got printed to the browser. It is important to note that this may depend on the browser.

However, if you try to insert/update a record into a database or save a log file, it works.

So, I would say, you can and you can not.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. And yes, I can't `echo` anything, because its content will be included in the file. Also, as you said, I'm updating a MySQL record; but I'd like to update it after the file have been fully downloaded by the client, otherwise just clicking and cancelling the file transfer adds 1 to the download count.

Comment: Read the file to a buffer, when it is ready, send to client and update the database. This will slow down the download and if two or more clients try to access the same file, they will be on hold while the first PHP process is reading the file.